# Why can't I use filters?

Tags: mcedit

I got a new filter for MCEdit but I can't use filters at all!  I can't select the option in MCEdit.  How can I use it?

Comment: 1) Have you installed the filter in MCedit's filters folder? 2) Is the filters button red?

Answer (score 2):

To use and install filters, you need to install it in the mcedit folder. For example, I have Mcedit on my desktop in a folder called mcedit. So my path that I need to drag and drop filters to is as follows: `C:\Users\username*\Desktop\mcedit\MCEdit-0.x.x.x\filters`

noting that the x's represent areas where you must fill in yourself as the versions may different. So find where you extracted MCedit and then open it up (not the .exe for windows) and then there should be a folder called filters. Once it is in there it should work :)

I recommend watching this video (not mine): [How to use and install mcedit filters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=te5-idTXr6o)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  Filters were installed in the correct location, but the Filters, Fill And Replace, and the Clone buttons were all RED.
Selecting the area and then clicking on Filters pops up an error box that says "Disable Error Notification" with an empty check box and an "Ok" button.

It turns out that while you can select chunks in the "overhead view" of the map,  you need to change it from Camera View to Chunk View to make any changes with the Filters.  You do this by clicking/toggling the 4th shortcut tab at the top of the screen from Camera View to Chunk View.

I hope this is helpful to you.
--M

Answer (score 0):

You must make a selection using the selection tool before you can use a filter.